# event.which in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Why doesn't `event.which` work in IE?

This my code, which works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

```
$("#inputFeild").keypress(function(event){
    alert(event.which);
});
```

`#inputFeild` is a textarea.

Comment: By the way, it's field not feild.

Comment: In what way does this code not work? It will alert the character code for printable keys in all browsers, and will vary a little for non-printable keys (such as arrow and function keys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `keypress` event in particular is unreliable for the keycode, use the appropriate event for whatever you're doing...for example if you need the value, use [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead:

```
$("#inputFeild").keyup(function(event){
  alert(event.which);
});
```

The [`.keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) documentation notes a few of these differences:

> Note that `keydown` and `keyup` provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while `keypress` indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by `keydown` and `keyup`, but as 97 by `keypress`. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes such as arrow keys, `.keydown()` or `.keyup()` is a better choice.

Comment: This answer is not up to your usual standards. What do you mean by "value"? The differentiation that needs to be made is between key codes and character codes, and which events to use for which.

Comment: The documentation is OK but weak. It should be more forceful about not using `keydown` and `keyup` for character detection. *"A lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by `keydown` and `keyup`"* is not universally true: it depends on the user's keyboard. This distinction is something that needs to be stated really clearly, as people are obviously confused.